# What causes StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() to fail with 1063 (ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-services

I'm seeing weird error with my Windows service program.  My service program calls `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` at the very beginning of its `main()`, but it sometime fails with `1063 (ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT)`.

I know that **this error occurs if the user starts program manually (as a console program).  But, it's not the case.**  I added a code to check the parent process of the service program when this error occurs, and it tells services.exe is the parent process (I think it's safe to assume that my program was properly started by SCM).

Unfortunately, this error does not reproduce on my dev machine and cannot debug it by myself, but the error logs captured on user systems tells:

- This problem seems to happen on only few % of the all users of this program.
- Even if the problem happens, it doesn't seem to repeat.  Next time the service usually starts successfully.
- When this problem happens, `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` stalls for about a second before it returns with fail.

Has anyone seen similar error?  If so, what was the cause of the error?

Comment: Have you double-checked that you are calling StartServiceCtrlDispatcher from the main thread, that it is being called within a few seconds of the process starting, and that the SERVICE_ENTRY_TABLE array is correct?  (In particular, make sure the final entry is {NULL, NULL}.)

Comment: Yes, SERVICE_ENTRY_TABLE is properly terminated.And, about the timing, I forgot to mention in my original question, but after StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() failure, my code checked time stamp and usually it's about one second (or less) after the service process started.  So, I'm thinking it's unlikely that the delay is causing the error.

Comment: Very odd.  And very hard to debug if you can't identify a common factor so you can reproduce the problem.  As a possible workaround, perhaps you could try calling StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() a second time if the first call fails?

Answer (score 8):

As you can already see from the absence of answers and anything on google, the problem isn't common. I believe the problem is in your service, AND it is in code executed from process's start to `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`, AND most likely it takes some form of corrupting system resources, likely heap or `HANDLE`'s.

You can be sorry to hear this, but I'm not going to have a magic answer to your problems. Instead, I can suggest some troubleshooting.

Microsoft Application Verifier is invaluable in finding corruption. I suggest that you:

1. Install it to your dev machine.
2. Add your service's exe to it.
3. Only select `Basics\Heaps` for the first time.
4. Press Save. It doesn't matter if you keep application verifier open.
5. Run your service a few times.
6. If it crashes, debug it and the crash will point to your problem.
7. If it doesn't crash, add `Basics\Handles`. Unlike `Basics\Heaps`, this can sometimes fire "false positives" - mistakes in code that doesn't hurt much. Anyway, since you're on the hunt, you'd better fix everything you can find. I'm mostly worried about double-freeing a `HANDLE` or something like that. Freeing a Service manager `HANDLE` by mistake can surely lead to your problem.
8. If it still doesn't crash, you can try other options in `Basics\*`, but I don't think that will help.
9. At this point, you might want to inspect the code between program's `main()` and `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()`, and any global constructors you can have. Look for potential buffer overflows and errors with `HANDLE`'s.
10. The next step could be installing Application Verifier to the client's machine. There's not much harm in it, I sometimes do it when I can't find the error myself.

Answer (score 0):

TIP: I used _wfopen/fwrite/fclose to log some messages. Somehow 183 was thrown internally and was leading to this failure 1063. I removed logging and it started working normally as nothing happen. Any minute error may lead you to it. Start from services and it will list the wage error (183 in my case).